# TimeOut Expired comes with SetResultTransformer() method

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My NH Query

```
exec sp_executesql N'IF @p0 = 1 SET @p1 = DATEADD(d, 1, @p1)   
SELECT b.fInvoiceID,  
b.fItemID,  
b.fAccount,  
e.fName AccountName,  
b.fDescription,  
b.fAmount,  
c.fCode CTCode,  
f.fDescription CTCodeName,  
c.fDescription CTDescription,  
c.fAmount CTAmount  
FROM         tAPInvoice       a   
INNER JOIN tAPInvoiceDetail b ON a.fInvoiceID = b.fInvoiceID  
INNER JOIN tSCLedgerAccount e ON b.fAccount = e.fAccount AND a.fCompanyID = e.fCompanyID   
LEFT JOIN  tCTActual        c ON b.fItemID = c.fAPItemID  
LEFT JOIN  tCTCode          f ON c.fCode = f.fCode AND c.fProjectID = f.fProjectID  
LEFT JOIN  tAPPayment       p ON a.fInvoiceID = p.fInvoiceID  
LEFT JOIN  tBACheck         d ON p.fCheckID = d.fCheckID  
INNER JOIN tAPVendor        v ON v.fVendorID = a.fVendorID  
WHERE   
((@p3 = ''Fully Paid''   AND a.fPaid = 1 AND a.fVoid = 0  ) OR   
(@p3 = ''Part Paid''    AND a.fPartPaid = 1 AND a.fVoid = 0  ) OR   
(@p3 = ''Payment Made''   AND a.fPartPaid = 1 AND a.fVoid = 0  ) OR   
(@p3 = ''Payment Made'' AND a.fPaid = 1   AND a.fVoid = 0                   ) OR   
(@p3 = ''Pending''   AND a.fPaid = 0 AND a.fPartPaid = 0 AND a.fVoid = 0 AND a.fPosted = 0 ) OR   
(@p3 = ''Posted''    AND a.fPosted = 1 ) OR   
(@p3 = ''Unpaid''  AND a.fPaid = 0 AND a.fPartPaid = 0 AND a.fVoid = 0  ) OR   
(@p3 = ''Voided''  AND a.fVoid = 1 ) OR   
(@p3 = ''All'' ))  
AND (@p12 = p.fPaymentType OR @p12 = -1)  
AND (CASE WHEN @p0 = 1   
THEN   a.fEntryDate  
ELSE CASE @p3  
WHEN ''Fully Paid''   THEN d.fDate  
WHEN ''Part Paid''    THEN d.fDate  
WHEN ''Payment Made'' THEN d.fDate  
WHEN ''Voided''       THEN a.fVoidDate  
ELSE                     a.fPostDate  
END  
END BETWEEN @p16 AND @p1)  
AND (a.fCompanyID = @p18 OR @p18 IS NULL)  
AND (a.fPropertyID =@p20 OR @p20 IS NULL)   
AND (a.fVendorID = @p22 OR @p22 IS NULL)   
AND (a.fUser = @p24 OR @p25 IS NULL)  
AND (v.fActive = @p26 OR @p26 IS NULL)  
ORDER BY a.fInvoiceNo ASC, b.fItemID, c.fCTID   ',N'@p0 bit,@p1 datetime,@p3 nvarchar(4000),@p12 int,@p16 datetime,@p18 nvarchar(4000),@p20 nvarchar(4000),@p22 nvarchar(4000),@p24 nvarchar(4000),@p25 nvarchar(4000),@p26 bit',@p0=0,@p1='2012-10-31 20:35:23',@p3=N'Fully Paid',@p12=-1,@p16='2012-07-01 20:35:23',@p18=NULL,@p20=NULL,@p22=NULL,@p24=NULL,@p25=NULL,@p26=1
```

Below is my c# code

```
sqlQuery =
          session.CreateSQLQuery(finalQuery).
          SetGuid("CompanyID", Company.FCompanyID).
          SetString("PropertyID", null).
          SetString("VendorID", null).
          SetDateTime("StartDate", StartDate).
          SetDateTime("EndDate", EndDate).
          SetString("Username", User).
          SetInt32("PaymentMethod", PaymentMethod).
          SetString("InvoiceType", invoicetype).
          SetString("UserName", User).
          SetBoolean("UseEntryDate", UserEntryDate).
          SetParameter("Active", Active);
```

after this i am using SetResultTransformer method

```
var result = sqlQuery.SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean<ReportData_APBI_Detail>()).List();
```

above line with SetResultTransformer() method throw an exception message

**{"Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."}**

even i run this query on Sql Server which give me output with in 48 sec.

Comment: Have you tried increasing your timeout?

Comment: Did you check SQL Server side to see what's going on? Query made by NHibernate may not be so optimal. BTW I would **not increase timeout** because you'll just hide where true problem is (untuned query, missing/not tuned indices or something else). 48 seconds are a LOT for a query unless you're working with a HUGE amount of data with a VERY complex query.

Comment: i checked and it give me result within 48 secs

Comment: @SunilNaudiyal No, I don't mean to run more or less same query on SQL Management Console. I would check how query generated by NH runs (at least trace generated query to see its timing).

Comment: i updated my question with NH query please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like run time exceeds default command timeout, you can configure it, 2 mins for example...

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
  <property name="command_timeout">120</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: hi thanks its works.but is there any other way without command timeout define on configuration file.i want define timeout only for this query not for hole.it is possible?.

Comment: `sqlQuery.setTimeout(120);`